# Can the Twisted logger log in UTC?

Tags: python, logging, twisted

If I log with `logging`, I can force the timestamp to be in UTC time by setting

```
logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime
```

like this:

```
import sys
import time
import logging

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
out_fmt = '[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03dZ] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s'
dt_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime
formatter = logging.Formatter(out_fmt, dt_fmt)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(10)
root.addHandler(handler)
logging.log(logging.INFO, 'Start logging')
```

Since my application will be using Twisted, I want to use `twisted.logger` instead for logging. And, indeed, it is much simpler:

```
import sys

from twisted.logger import Logger, textFileLogObserver

log = Logger(observer=textFileLogObserver(sys.stdout, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
log.info('Start logging')
```

Problem is, the timestamp is in local time - not in UTC time. Is there a way to make the Twisted logger use UTC time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up overriding `formatTime` in `FileLogObserver`:

```py
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from twisted.python import log


def myFLOformatTime(self, when):
    timeFormatString = self.timeFormat
    if timeFormatString is None:
        timeFormatString = '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fZ]'
    return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(when).strftime(timeFormatString)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log.FileLogObserver.formatTime = myFLOformatTime
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
```